# Doing like search in oracle?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate

I have below code now.
I am getting list of strings from the UI as below. the list has 3 strings as shown below.

```
happy%
%hai
%hello%
```

now i am looping through all 3 strings and getting matching strings and adding them to final list as below.

```
for(int i=0;i<list.size;i++){
//query to perform like search...
}
```

My question is , instead of firing a separate query, how can i include them in a single query?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `OR` operator with that three strings you are getting like

`where name like 'happy%' or name like '%appy' or name like '%ppy%'`

Comment: Can't use regexp_like function here? Thanks!

Comment: There is a function in oracle by name regexp_like(). can i use it here?

Comment: `or name like '%ppy%'` this condition includes rest of 2 conditions

Answer (score 1):

You can do several queries depending on the requirements. If all three need to be in the result then you use `AND` like so:

```
SELECT st 
FROM SampleTable st 
WHERE ( st.col1 LIKE 'happy%' ) AND ( st.col2 LIKE '%hai' )
AND ( st.col3 LIKE '%hello%' )
```

You can also use `OR`, or you can mix and match the two. The `OR` works in the same way as the `AND` from the previous result and parenthases help when writing complex queries.

Furthermore, you can use the `NOT` keyword to exclude certain results, which can look like so:

```
SELECT st 
FROM SampleTable st 
WHERE ( st.col1 LIKE 'happy%' ) AND ( st.col2 NOT LIKE '_hai' )
```

*Note:* `_` is for one character matches, while `%` is for many.